# What is difference between the "usual multiplication" and multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic

I have been reading books in the algebra, and I noticed that some books use terms "usual multiplication" and "usual addition".  Do they carry different meaning that multiplication and addition?  If "usual" means something, is there such things as "usual division and subtraction"?

Comment: What are you adding or multiplying? Numbers? If so, what kind of numbers?

Comment: I am reading the definition:  it said the group must be closed under usual multiplication, but I am feeling unease since I never encountered the word "usual".

Comment: The definition of what? A generic group, or a particular one?

Comment: General group...

Comment: Do we know what the underlying set is?

Comment: It is defined to be a finite set; I do not have specific parameter for a set as the definition is just a general group

Comment: Can someone answer my question?

Comment: As the question is right now, I don't deem it possible. I suggest writing down the whole incriminated sentence (along with the entirety of the sensible context) inside the question and see from there, since the comments so far are inadequate to reconstruct it.

Comment: It is from Dummit/Foote's algebra book, where they describe the binary operations as usual multplication and addition, which unease me as I am not sure what it means by usual.

Comment: When I checked other books like Herstein, they did not use word "usual", and D/F's descriptions of "usual" multiplication and addition are same as other books.  I am curious if there is any extra meaning for "usual".

Comment: When someone in an abstract algebra book says "standard" or "usual" or "ordinary" addition or multiplication, they mean the operations that most people understand those to be from "grade-school" arithmetic.  This is as opposed to, say, modular arithmetic, vector multiplication(s), and all sorts of other extensions of these binary operations.

Comment: In my copy of D&F, I only see the definition of a group *followed by examples* of groups: Number sets we all know and love with their *usual* addition/multiplication, like @RecklessReckoner points out. So it is not the definition of a "generic" group at all, but examples of specific groups that work "exactly how you think they do," (Unless you're looking elsewhere besides the definition of a group in chapter 1)

Comment: My experience with textbooks in abstract algebra is that if the author(s) do(es) not intend the use of ordinary arithmetic, but is using the symbols " + " and " x " ( or " $ \cdot $ " ) to denote binary operations, they will have said somewhere in defining the algebra  "addition" or "multiplication as defined by..." and describe how the operator works in some fashion.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Now I can think that the binary operations (multiplication, addition, subtraction, and division) for the groups can range from usual to vector to modular operations, and "usual" operations are what we typically know: scalar arithmetics.

Comment: This post and its long comment thread are an excellent example of why it's important to ask a good question in the first place. If more of the context, and an actual quote, had been included in the original question, the first repsonder could have answered it completely.

Comment: &Greg Martin Alright, I understand your point.

Comment: I want to point out here that "usual" does not necessarily mean "scalar operations", for example, the "usual" addition in $\Bbb R^2$ is defined: $(x,y) + (x',y') = (x+x',y+y')$ where the plus signs on the RHS  are from the "usual" addition of the real numbers-in other words the "usual" addition in $\Bbb R^2$ is *vector* (or *component-wise*) addition.

Answer (score 1):

"Usual multiplication" in this sense refers to the elementary definition of multiplication which is when a number $a$ is added to itself multiple times (we'll call the frequency $b$), which is thought as repeated addition: $a \times b = \underbrace{a + \cdots + a}_{\text{$b$ times}}$. However, just "multiplication" in this sense refers to the combining of matrices, vectors or any other sort of quantities under certain rules (probably used most in abstract algebra) to get a certain product. Basically, "usual" refers to elementary. I'm sure "usual subtraction" and "usual division" do exist like "usual addition" and "usual multiplication" because they all refer to the elementary use of these operations. Do note that in abstract algebra, we only use the addition and multiplication operations because subtraction and division can be rewritten in addition and multiplication respectively.

So, the bottom line is..."usual multiplication" is elementary multiplication, which is NOT the same thing as mutliplication in abstract algebra. Same goes for addition.